# Remove table row if specific cell has been emptied jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a two-column table that displays a list of filters, and those filters can be removed by clicking a little "x" icon next to each:

```
<tr>
    <td class="filter-point">State is</td>
    <td class="tag-column"><div class="tag">California <i class="fa fa-close"></i></div></td>
</tr>

$("td.tag-column .tag i").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

I want to be able to remove the entire row if all of the tags have been removed (if td.tag-column is empty), but I can't seem to figure out the right syntax or method for attaching the row emptying to the tag emptying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extend your current click event to check, after each tag removal, if the row has any tags left:

```
$("td.tag-column .tag i").click(function(){
    var td = $(this).closest('td');
    $(this).parent().remove(); //remove tag
    if (!td.children('.tag').length) td.parent().remove(); //if no tags left, remove row
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like following.

```
$("td.tag-column .tag i").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.find('.tag').length || tr.remove();
});
```